# How to avoid in login twice in my admin panel (PHP)

Tags: php

I created an admin panel where i can edit my website but i always need to login twice before i can access my admin panel. How am i able to avoid that?

I am working in an existing admin panel with just one time login i copied everything in my portal but the result is i still need to login twice.

Here's my connection.

```
<?php
$errormsg = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $email             = $_POST['email'];
  $pass              = $_POST['password'];
  $salt              = sha1(md5($pass));
  $passwordencrypted = md5($pass . $salt);

  $stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT count(*) as count FROM users WHERE email=?");
  $stmt->execute(array($email));

  while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row_count = $row['count'];
  }

  if ($row_count == 1)
  {
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where email = :name");
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':name' => "$email"
    ));

    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $userID      = $row['userID'];
        $lpass       = $row['password'];
        $userlevelID = $row['userlevelID'];
    }
    if ($lpass == $passwordencrypted) {
      $_SESSION["userID"]      = $userID;
      $_SESSION["userlevelID"] = $userlevelID;
      if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
          $pipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
          $ipaddress  = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
          $ipaddd     = "Logged In using Proxy IP address is: " . $pipaddress . "(via $ipaddress)";
      } else {
          $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
          $ipaddd    = "Logged In using IP address: $ipaddress";
      }

      $currentdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $auditaction = "Logged In";
      $auditdetail = $ipaddd;

      $stmt        = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO audittrail(userID,[action],detail,[when]) VALUES(:uid,:action,:detail,:when)");
      $stmt->execute(array(
          ':uid' => $userID,
          ':action' => $auditaction,
          ':detail' => $auditdetail,
          ':when' => $currentdatetime
      ));

      $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
      /////////////////////////////////////////
      //$_SESSION['timeOut'] = 5;
      $_SESSION['timeOut'] = 600;
      $logged = time();
      $_SESSION['loggedAt']= $logged;

      if ($userlevelID == 1) {
      } elseif ($userlevelID == 2) {
          header("location:portal/");
      }

    } else {
        header("location:index.php?error=c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b"); // 1
    }
    }
    else {
      header("location:index.php?error=c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c"); //2
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check session value when user on login page of admin panel. Redirect him on main page of admin panel if session value is present.

Answer (score 1):

At the `index.php` page:

Add in the following code:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['isLoggedIn']) { 
    header(Location: adminpage.php);
}
```

This will redirect users when the `$_SESSION` is true, and will stay at the login page if the `$_SESSION` is not set.

Comment: I didn't work and there's a error log in notepad it says.  [18-Feb-2016 04:48:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /home/truenorth/public_html/webportal/core/db/connection.php:4

Comment: Don't forget to [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) after issuing the redirection header.